# Session management/revocation with OAuth2 and OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, openid

Assuming I have a scenario where a user logs in to a client application via an identity provider using the OAuth2/OpenID Connect flow, how do I manage the user deciding to revoke the client's access to their profile? That is, how do I make sure the client application automatically terminates the local session?

Is there a recommended way to implement session management at the client application level when signing in using an external provider as explained above?

**TL;DR: How do I implement single-sign-out using the OAuth2/OpenID Connect flow?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [OpenID Session management draft](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html):

> This specification complements the OpenID Connect Core 1.0
> [OpenID.Core] specification by defining how to monitor the End-User's
> login status at the OpenID Provider on an ongoing basis so that the
> **Relying Party can log out an End-User who has logged out** of the OpenID
> Provider.

There is also a bit of documentation on the subject on the internet:

- https://medium.com/@technospace/managing-sessions-with-openid-connect-d3b6fb4f552b
- https://oa.dnc.global/web/-OpenID-Connect-SSO-management-de-session-etc-.html#draftmanagementdesessionopenidconnect
- https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/check-session

You can also check how django-oidc-provider manage this:
https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/sessionmanagement.html